# unresolved external symbol error even when setup of visual studio project is done properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries, static-linking

## In a nutshell

I am tring to use an existing C++ library.
The problem is that it's not compiled.
I took the src code (a visual studio project) and tried to compile it.
The thing is that I can't link my project to the library.

## More specific details are:

### What I have already done is the following:

1. I opened the `.sln` file and added another sub-project called "Sampler"
2. I downloaded all Microsoft additional packages that the library src code depends on.
3. I compiled the library to Windows 32 platform x86 (using Visual Studio 2022). The compilation was successful.
4. I created a directory `Dependencies\OPCClientToolKit` in same directory of `.sln` file, `Dependencies\OPCClientToolKit` contains two directories `include` and `lib`.
5. I put in `Dependencies\OPCClientToolKit\lib` the `.lib` - the output after compilation.
6. I put in `Dependencies\OPCClientToolKit\include` the `.h` files of the src code of sdk library.
7. I added a dependency `.h` files via Sampler Project > Properies > C++ General. See pictures below.
8. I added a dependency folder `Dependencies\OPCClientToolKit\lib` via Sampler Project > Properies > Linker General. See pictures below.
9. I added a dependency `OPCClientToolKit.lib` via Sampler Project > Properies > Linker Input. See pictures below.

As far as I know all my step seems valid and fine.

But when, I am compiling (hitting Build via Visual Studio) the Sampler project code (see the code below) I am getting an error message:

##### Error Message:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Sampler, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Sampler.cpp
1>Sampler.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class COPCHost * __cdecl COPCClient::makeHost(class ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,class ATL::StrTraitATL<wchar_t,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > > const &)" (?makeHost@COPCClient@@SAPAVCOPCHost@@ABV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitATL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@ATL@@@ATL@@@Z)
1>C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Projects\PID\OPC_DA\Release\Sampler.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "Sampler.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Please explain to me how should I resolve this issue. I just want to include and use this library and not to modify it.**

#### Dependecies\OPCClientToolKit\lib

[image]

#### Dependecies\OPCClientToolKit\include

[image]

#### Sampler Project > Properties > C++ > General

[image]

#### Sampler Project > Properties > Linker > General

[image]

#### Sampler Project > Properties > Linker > Input

[image]

#### I am using this library (OPC client sdk):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/opcclient/

#### A usage example made by other guy on the internet:

https://github.com/Tibalt/OPC_DA/blob/master/OPCClientDemo/OPCClientDemo.cpp

#### My code just use functions and objects of that library.

In details, just trying to initialize opc connection to a server on localhost:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys\timeb.h>
#include "opcda.h"
#include "OPCClient.h"
#include "OPCHost.h"
#include "OPCServer.h"
#include "OPCGroup.h"
#include "OPCItem.h"
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    COPCClient::init();
    cout << "Done Init";
    cout << endl;
    CString hostName = "localhost";
    COPCHost* host = COPCClient::makeHost(hostName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That project OPCClientToolKit is very old. It looks like built with using ANSI character set, without using the macro `_UNICODE`. You should either

1. Remove the macro `_UNICODE` from the preprocessor settings in your project.
2. Or add that entire project OPCClientToolKit as a dependency to your visual studio solution and add the macro `_UNICODE` to that project.
3. Or use the solution of that project OPCClientToolKit and rebuild the static library OPCClientToolKit.lib with the macro `_UNICODE`.